# Is there any way to keep an app logged in even if the app is force closed?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to keep a user logged into an app even if they double click the home button and swipe my app away (force close). Similar to how snapchat is.

I would like them to only be able to logout if they personally click the logout button.

How can i implement this?

I am using Swift and Parse. Thank you.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: What does it mean to your app for a user to be logged in?  Are you using OAuth or some other mechanism?  Chances are there will be other reasons for them to be logged out other than clicking the button: app uninstall, token expiration, they changed their password somewhere else, etc.

Comment: @Mr.T I am actually quite new to iOS, Self-learning so i don't even know where to begin.

Comment: @i_am_jorf for my app, i need it to remain logged in so no one else would have access to it with their username and password.

Comment: you can simply try saving a token in nsuserdefaults and based on it, you can skip the log in session!!!

Answer (score 1):

The iOS Keychain is a good option. Since maintaining a session means keeping a session token of some kind, `NSUserDefaults` is not secure and would not be the way to go.

Comment: Also, `NSUserDefaults` data is deleted when you delete the app, and Keychain data stays. Keychain gives you fine-grained control on data transfer when backing up device, let's you require a passcode set to save the data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to keep an app running if the app is force closed, but that doesn't mean you have to log the user out.

The standard way to handle this is to store the authorization token/info so that if the app is killed and restarted, then it will act exactly as if it was always logged in.

Comment: How do i go about doing this? Fairly new to coding, 4 months.

Comment: You said you are using Parse. It's already done for you in Parse, so you don't have to do anything at all.

Comment: From Parse's docs: Whenever you use any signup or login methods, the user is cached on disk. You can treat this cache as a session, and automatically assume the user is logged in...